# How to make an operator replace the previous operator in a calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm building a calculator but i'm left with one problem and that is repeating operators. For example if i input '5x' and i decide to change the multiplication sign to plus sign  '+' the result should be '5+' instead
Below is a copy of my code

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousDisplayTextElement, currentDisplayTextElement) {
        this.currentDisplayTextElement = currentDisplayTextElement;
        this.previousDisplayTextElement = previousDisplayTextElement;
        this.clear();
    } 
    clear() {
        this.currentDisplay = '';
        this.previousDisplay = '';
        this.operation = ' ';
    }
   delete() {
      this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString().substr(0, this.currentDisplay.length - 1);
   }
   appendNumber(number) { 
    if(number === "." && this.currentDisplay.includes('.')) return;
      if (this.currentDisplay === '0') {
        this.currentDisplay = number.toString();
      } else {
        this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString() +  number.toString();
      } 
   }
   selectOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentDisplay === '') return;
     if (this.previousDisplay !== '') { 
        this.solve(); 
     }

     this.operation = operation; 
     this.previousDisplay = this.currentDisplay;
     console.log('correct sequence')
     this.currentDisplay = '';
    
 }
   solve() {
      let evaluation;
      const prev = parseFloat(this.previousDisplay);
      const current = parseFloat(this.currentDisplay);
      if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
      switch (this.operation) {
        case "+":
            evaluation = prev + current;
            break;
        case "-":
            evaluation = prev - current;
            break;
        case "x":
            evaluation = prev * current;
            break;
        case "÷":
            evaluation = prev / current;
            break;
          default:
            return;  
      }
      this.currentDisplay = evaluation;
      this.operation = ''
      this.previousDisplay = ""; 
   }
   showDisplayNumber(number) {
    const floatNumber = parseFloat(number);
     if (isNaN(floatNumber)) return '';
     
     return floatNumber;
   }
   updateDisplay() {
     this.currentDisplayTextElement.value = this.showDisplayNumber(this.currentDisplay);
     if (this.operation != null) {
        this.previousDisplayTextElement.value = `${this.showDisplayNumber(this.previousDisplay)} ${this.operation}`;
     } else {
        this.previousDisplayTextElement.value = '';
     }
   }
}
const currentDisplayTextElement = document.querySelector(['#operations']);
const previousDisplayTextElement = document.querySelector(['#previous-display']); 
const clearButton = document.querySelector(['.clear-All']);
const deleteButton = document.querySelector(['.delete']);
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(['.digits']);
const mathOperands = document.querySelectorAll(['.data-operations']);
const equalsButton = document.querySelector(['.equals']);
const calculator = new Calculator(previousDisplayTextElement, currentDisplayTextElement);

numberButtons.forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
                calculator.appendNumber(li.innerText);
                calculator.updateDisplay();
            })
    })
    mathOperands.forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
                calculator.selectOperation(li.innerText);
                calculator.updateDisplay();
            })
    })
        equalsButton.addEventListener('click', li => { 
                calculator.solve();
                calculator.updateDisplay();
            })
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', li => { 
                calculator.clear();
                calculator.updateDisplay();
            })
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', li => { 
                calculator.delete();
                calculator.updateDisplay();
            })

     //THEME       
    const darkTheme = document.getElementById('dark');
    const lightTheme = document.getElementById('light');
    const calcTheme = document.querySelector('div'); 

function light() {
    calcTheme.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
}
function dark() {
    calcTheme.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
}
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
const isDark = localStorage.getItem('dark');

if (theme) {
    calcTheme.classList.add(theme);
    isDark && calcTheme.classList.add('dark');
}






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Js Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Javascript Calculator</h1>
    <div id="main-div" class="light"> 
      <div class="screen">
        <input type="text"id="previous-display" readonly=""/>
        <input type="text" id= "operations" readonly="" />
      </div>
      <div class="mode">
        <i id="light" class="bi bi-brightness-high" aria-label="switch to light mode" onclick="light()"></i>
        <i id="dark" class="bi bi-moon" aria-label="switch to dark mode" onclick="dark()"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-operations" id="calc-op">
        <ul class="main-op">
          <li class="clear-All" id="special-sym">AC</li>
          <li   id="special-sym">(</li>
          <li   id="special-sym">)</li>
          <li class="data-operations" id="math-sym">÷</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">7</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">8</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">9</li>
          <li  class="data-operations" id="math-sym">x</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">4</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">5</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">6</li>
          <li  class="data-operations" id="math-sym">-</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">1</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">2</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">3</li>
          <li class="data-operations" id="math-sym">+</li>
          <li class="delete" id="special-sym">c</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">0</li>
          <li data-number class="digits">.</li>
          <li class="equals" id="math-sym">=</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="calculator.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried different methods to achieve it. My idea was to check the previous display for any existing operator and the new clicked operator should replace the previous one

How do you suggest I go about solving this problem?`your text`

Comment: I'd start selectOperation with checking if the last element in the string is in a list of valid operators. If it is I'd replace the last operator and if it isn't I'd append it. Sounds like that's what you already tried so how did you do that?